# String index. How to retrieve last 3 letters of strings

Tags: python

```
streetName = "Finley"
print(streetName[???]),
                   ^
                   |
```

I'm trying to find out how I can retrieve the last 3 letters of the string using string index. What would I put in the brackets??

Comment: Duplicate found was first search result on google for "How to retrieve last 3 letters of strings python"

Comment: what do you mean by string index? you can use `streetName[-3:]` to get last three characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(streetName[-3:]).
```

This should work.